# How can I get a GS1 datamatrix code (with separators) to a C# winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode, separator, datamatrix

I use a barcode scanner to read medecine GS1 datamatrix codes. I need the entire data sequence, including Group Separators to parse the code in order to seek for Application identifiers (AI) and get the data accordingly.
The target is a winforms C# application, it will call the NMVS services to check medecines status.
Actually i put a TextBox as the target control but its content does not contain the GS anymore.

Thank you for your help

If I manually fill the textbox with 0x1D (ASCII 29) chars as separators, it works like a charm. The GS1 parser finds the AI and I can extract data.
If I open Notepad++ with focus on it and scan a code, the special characters are present. I setup my scanner, NETUM C750 model, to map the function keys, so that the separators are included into the buffer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Very often the scanner chooses how to present the data from GS1 (FNC1) structured codes. And it may be an option in the scanner. You should post a sample of a barcode and perhaps the exact type of scanner you use (brand and model ID). This will make it simpler to help you.

Comment: I tried with random codes found on the Internet, simply entering  "gs1 datamatrix" as criterion. The scanner is a USB one, no driver needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Barcode scanner is considered a keyboard, I found out to catch the keypress event, so that I fill a char list.

```
List<char> charList = new List<char>();

private void textEditCode_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  charList.Add(e.KeyChar);
}
string datamatrix = new string(charList.ToArray()); //charList is filled      by pressing the keys, or when receiving data from the scanner
Aii = gS1.Parse(datamatrix); // Aii = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

After that, I parse the char list as the GS1 content, and I can call the NMVS service :

```
string Batch = gS1.GetValue(EGS1AI.Batch);
string ProductCode = gS1.GetValue(EGS1AI.GTIN);
System.DateTime ExpDate = gS1.GetValue(EGS1AI.ExpirationDate);
string SerialNumber = gS1.GetValue(EGS1AI.SerialNumber);
string dat = ExpDate.ToString("yyMMdd");

Log log = new Log(App.LogFolder(), App.AppName);

G110Response response = G110.G110Verify(ProductCode, Batch, dat, 
SerialNumber, log);
```

then process response

Answer (score 0):

I use barcode scanners to read GS1 data for incoming components. Ironically my better scanner (Netum NT-2128BL) drops the field separators while my worse one(Teradata 8100) passes them along. You might try another scanner. My separator is Unicode Character 'LEFT RIGHT ARROW' (U+2194). The separator is called a GS1 FNC1 character.
[GS1_datamatrix_sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgLvG.jpg)